# Ios6 compatibility with earlier versions

Tags: iphone

Since size of iPhone 5 bigger, view below 460 cannot be seen on iPhone 4.
Is there any way to make them compatible?
For e.g. size of items on view should be adjusted depending on full screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you can check your device is bigger or not... use the following code

```
int deviceType;

float height = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    if (height==568) {
        self.deviceType = 5;
    }
    else
    {
        self.deviceType = 4;
    }
```